# How to add style for Title of ContentPage in .Net MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui, winui-3, maui-windows

I'm working with .NET MAUI to create a desktop app.

Here, I have a `ContentPage` with the title **My title**.

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MAUI.Desktop.Pages.PlanningPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="My title">
....
```

Its title is aligned left by default, do you know how to align it to the center of the page? If possible, I also want to add more style to it too.
[image]

**Edit: suggested solution**

- I forget to mention that my page is considered `NavigationPage`. So, here is my solution:

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MAUI.Desktop.Pages.PlanningPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
>
 <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label
            x:Name="pageTitleView"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="My title"/>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
......
```

In code-behind `xaml.cs` file:

```
 protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
 {
     base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
     pageTitleView.WidthRequest = width;
 }
```

- If you're working with `Shell app`, you could follow the [answer from @mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74657045/12020710)

Comment: use `TitleView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your own `TitleView`:

```
<ContentPage                          x:Class="MAUI.Desktop.Pages.PlanningPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Planification">
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Label Text="My Title" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer works well in case I use `Shell App`. 
But actually, my `ContentPage` is set up as a `NavigationPage`, so I have to modify the solution a little bit.
I accept the answer anyway. Thanks for your time